# replacing dynamic string

Tags: javascript, replace

I need JavaScript code for replacing a substring of given string.

I have a variable say:

```
var c="<name='abc'&id='123'/>";
```

I need to replace the name='abc' with name='def'. 'abc' is a dynamic value so the replace function must do a match and replace.

End result required:

```
<name='def'&id='123'/>
```

Can you give me an example how to do this?

Comment: `Var` should probably be `var`, and, just to make sure, you know that's not valid HTML, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
c = c.replace(/name='[^']+'/, "name='def'");
```

It's hard to tell from your question exactly what you're after...